# Why implementing CSS "text-align-last" proprety instead of pseudo-element i.e. "::last-line"

Tags: css

In CSS, we have been introduced the new property `text-align-last` property to align the last line, but to me, this is going out of the regular flow of CSS. We already have pseudo-element selectors like `::first-line`, so instead of implementing `text-align-last` property, a pseudo-element selector *i.e.* `::last-line` could have been introduced where we could do more than just aligning the text.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: @rifkyNiyas my question is not seeking technical support but to know why W3.org didn't implement pseudo-element i.e. `::last-line` for this purpose instead they just used property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agreed! Your suggestion would make sense. It's consistent and it would also match the other pseudo elements like `:first-child` and `:last-child`.

Maybe you could suggest it to W3C?
They have an archived mailing list **www-style@w3.org**. You could subscribe yourself and take part in discussions:
https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/

More info for if you want to help/participate can be found here:
https://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/current-work

Answer (score 0):

Your question is similar to: why did we invent big calculators and big PC when we could have invented the powerful small laptops we have now?

`text-align-last` was created for a purpose and a need that has emerged: to *only* align the last line.

What you are asking for is a different thing: A selector to select the last line to apply CSS. Maybe it will come in future and maybe not. It depends if we really need it and if the communit ask for it. It make look trivial for you but it's not. A lot a feature were never implemented until now due to a lot of limiation. the `:has()` selector was introduced since more than 5 years now and we still have no support for it due to many implementations limitation.

This is how CSS worked since the beginning.

Why having `:first-child`\ `:last-child` if we can do everything with `nth-child(n)` ?

Why having `top`,`left`,`right`,`bottom` if we can use only `inset`?

etc

This is the evolution of CSS.

Comment: Well function of big computer and small laptop is same and they both are computers. My question is when pseudo elements Selectors are used for same purpose than they shouldn't have gone for property for it, this way will.be easy for us to find selectors and properties, and there is no problem both `:first-child` & `nth-child` because both are selectors, similar case is for position properties.